# Wheaton's law rewritten as a company policy / company value

Tags: politics, company-policy, motivation

[Wheaton's law:](https://www.attorneyatwork.com/wheatons-law/) "Don't be a dick", we feel would be a excellent company policy or company value. But for obvious reasons we can not use that verbatim.

What would be a more work appropriate way of phrasing that, while still capturing the simplicity and directness, without being overly prescriptive?

Comment: This seems too broad or opinion-based for this site - there are too many possible answers. Some examples: Be nice, be kind, be respectful, don't be mean, don't be a jerk, treat each other well, be empathetic, act with compassion. You can probably grab a thesaurus to come up with a few dozen more.

Comment: Tbh, I think this is something that should apply in general to *any* situation, not just in the Workplace. It should just be assumed as the basis of decent behavior. So, I'm not sure it would be very helpful as a written company policy.

Answer (score 2):

Wheaton's Law seems mostly to be a variation on the [Golden Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Rule), which you can just use directly:

> Treat other the way you want to be treated.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't be useful. Everybody's definition of "dick-like" behavior is different and hence it wouldn't result in a consistent policy or consistent behavior. A good behavioral policy needs to specific enough so that that the judgement of what's acceptable and not acceptable behavior is not open to personal interpretation or definition.

Answer (score 0):

> "Grow up mate."

is my personal favourite, gives the correct message while not being particularly offensive. But any variation on 'act your age' or 'play fair' can be appropriate dependent on the circumstances.

I once saw a sign that said 'We're a team, work together and act like one. Save the BS for outsiders.' I'm unsure what BS means though.